# Why this function for JFrame is executed twice?

Tags: java, user-interface

**Introduction**

I'm learning how to present GUIs for user 'friendly' input. I will reference below some web pages for those who are interested in the matter.

**Code**

```
public class TestGUI{

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public TestGUI()
    {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    private void prepareGUI()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("TestGUI"); //Header name
        mainFrame.setSize(420, 320); //Size of the frame
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1)); //??

       mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() //Waits for an user event
       {
         //When the frame is closes, the program does too.
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
         {
            System.exit(0); //Exit program
         }        
      });

       mainFrame.setVisible(true);//GUI is visible
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestGUI test = new TestGUI(); //constructor
        test.prepareGUI(); //Call the method
    }

}
```

**Problem**

While running the code I saw that 2 identical frames pop up. I went to debug it and saw that it is executed twice when I call the method!

**Why is that?**

I only called it once with `testGUI.prepareGUI();` in the main function.

**Webpages for learning basic GUI in Java**

[JavaFX](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/CatalogJavaFX.htm)

[GUI Programming with AWT](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j4a_gui.html)

Comment: Remove `test.prepareGUI();` from main method or do not call `prepareGUI();` method inside constructor. If you want to `JFrame` only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `prepareGUI()` in the constructor as well.

```
public TestGUI()
{
    prepareGUI();
}
```

When you call `new TestGUI()`, this constructor gets called and so does the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling prepareGui twice

Once here

```
  public TestGUI()
    {
        prepareGUI();
    }
```

and once here

```
    TestGUI test = new TestGUI(); //constructor
    test.prepareGUI(); //Call the method
```

so first block is executed on new TestGUI() call

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `prepareGui()` method twice. One in your constructor and once on your created object (in the `main` method)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that constructor (that is TestGUI()) you are already calling prepareGUI(). so just omit the other call to prepareGUI(), which is test.prepareGUI().